# How to copy multi-line data from data item in Blue prism

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I have multi-line data in data item when I copy.  How can I get the data line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so, you can use for example this action:

```
object: Utility - Strings manipulation C#
action: Extract regex values
input:
 text - string you want to split
 RegEx - ".+\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

try using "Utility - Strings" and action "Split Lines"..this takes a text data item as input and splits the data into a collection having multiple rows..